# ScreenSaveTimeOut is reset by some process, so my changes are not preserved. how do I find a process that does it?

Tags: windows, screensaver, regedit

my work-issued Windows-XP laptop goes into "secure" screensaver after 15 mins, which is annoying if I show a webcast or some such.

resetting the value in GUI or via regedit does not hold for long as I see the same default (900) ScreenSaveTimeOut value after a while (did not find how long yet).

how do catch this resetting process/script/whatever it is?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite likely that the value is being reset by the group policy set by your IT department, so the changes you make via the UI or registry are being overwritten next time the policy refreshes.

I'd talk to your IT department and explain the problem. They might exempt your machine from this part of the policy (however, I don't know how easy this would be).